# Wear OS Watch Face Transition Animation

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

Stock Samsung watch faces that come with Watch 6 have this wonderful animations that are displayed when user activates/switches to the face from the face selection screen. The hands of the clock transition from the position that is fixed in the preview image to the position corresponding to the actual time. This provides a smooth transition from the preview image of the system's face selection screen to the actual watch face.

You can see examples of these animations at the beginning of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3w-q977y74

Similar animations are also played when you switch out of the watch face where hands of the clock transition quickly from the actual time to the position that corresponds to the position in the fixed face's preview, which again gives a smooth transition from the watch face to the preview image.

I am trying to develop a watch face using Jetpack Watch Face APIs and Kotlin language. I cannot find the proper triggers/events that I could listen to to know that my watch face has just been activated/selected or that my watch face is going into the "background" (and system's watch face selection screen is about to get displayed), so that I could trigger the same type of animations in my code.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: did u get any solution?

Comment: No, none so far.